# Keep lines based on ratio between lines

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I have a `sort -g k9` command on a file that gives me this in the bash standard output:

```
55.19   645 156 15  9   520 58  702 0.0  661
55.50   636 159 16  9   520 58  693 0.0  654
55.19   645 156 15  9   520 58  702 0.0  658
56.52   644 147 16  9   520 59  701 0.0  669
55.97   645 151 15  9   520 65  709 0.0  672
55.97   645 151 15  9   520 65  709 4e-124   674
28.32   671 301 32  1   507 48  702 3e-49    183
28.32   671 301 32  1   507 47  701 3e-49    183
31.40   516 247 24  86  507 196 698 1e-46    176
31.41   519 243 25  86  507 196 698 5e-46    175
27.72   588 290 26  19  481 98  675 2e-39    154
30.56   337 170 17  101 413 302 598 5e-20   96.3
30.56   337 170 17  101 413 302 598 8e-20   95.5
```

I would like to cut my data based on the 9th column. The idea would be to compare the value of the 9th column on line *i*, divide it by the value of the 9th column on line *i+1*, and if the **ratio is 0 OR 0/0 OR > 1e-50**, line *i* and *i+1* are kept. As soon as one of these conditions is not filled, stop reading. The desired output would be:

```
55.19   645 156 15  9   520 58  702 0.0  661
55.50   636 159 16  9   520 58  693 0.0  654
55.19   645 156 15  9   520 58  702 0.0  658
56.52   644 147 16  9   520 59  701 0.0  669
55.97   645 151 15  9   520 65  709 0.0  672
55.97   645 151 15  9   520 65  709 4e-124   674
```

I can obtain this output with `head -n 6` but this is obviously not based on the condition on values in the 9th column. Please note that the values are in 'scientific' format.

I know how to do this in Python (write the standard output to a file, calculate ratios, etc.) but for commodity reasons I'd prefer a shell-based solution (with `awk` or `sort` for instance) although I don't know if that's possible. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exit the script when the condition is not accomplished; otherwise, print the previous line and store the 9th field to compare on the next loop:

```
$ awk '($9 && prev/$9>1e-50) {exit} {print stored; prev=$9; stored=$0}' file

55.19   645 156 15  9   520 58  702 0.0  661
55.50   636 159 16  9   520 58  693 0.0  654
55.19   645 156 15  9   520 58  702 0.0  658
56.52   644 147 16  9   520 59  701 0.0  669
55.97   645 151 15  9   520 65  709 0.0  672
55.97   645 151 15  9   520 65  709 4e-124   674
```